# decompiling chm file: hh.exe requires only the filename. no full path is allowed

Tags: shell, filenames, chm, regedit

I noticed that `hh.exe` is capable of decompiling a .chm file to a set of .html files. But in order to work it requires the path to the file be current directory and the filename be the filename itself, **apparently without allowing a full path**.

For example, this will work (in cmd):

```
c:\MyDir>hh -decompile extracted MyFile.chm
```

This won't work:

```
c:\>hh -decompile extracted c:\MyDir\MyFile.chm
```

This is relevant because I want to use a shell command from the registry to decompile the .chm file, and the parameter "`%1`" gives me the full path to the file only, and I don't know of a way to receive only the filename without the path

Comment: Another issue is the arguments cannot be enclosed in quotes. 

For example c:>hh -decompile "extracted" "c:\MyDir\MyFile.chm"
Will not work. this is annoying when the chm file has spaces in it.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing forward slash eg:

```
c:\>hh -decompile extracted c:/MyDir/MyFile.chm
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to open command line in the folder containing your .chm file,
try 'shift' key and 'right click' mouse button and "Open command window here" option.
Make sure no file is sellected.
regards, joe

Answer (score 0):

It won't work with paths quoted or otherwise.

It's easiest to just move the output folder and input *.chm into the root of the drive, cd there, and then simply run the `hh.exe -decompile outputfolder input.chm` command.